# How i add dynamic checkboxes on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

I'm trying to add dynamic checkbox on a search for users when i search for the user id they list all products and check only products the user are able to see. I don't know how to compare all the products and specific user products.

When i add the second foreach the code return an error

Blade View

```
       @foreach($todos_planos as $key => $todos_planos)
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>
            @foreach($produto_plano as $produto_plano) 
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_prodcomerc[{{$key}}]" 
            name="id_prodcomerc[{{$key}}]" value="id_prodcomerc[{{$key}}
            {{ $produto_plano->id_produto == $todos_planos->id_prodcomerc 
            ? 'checked' : '' }}>
            @endforeach
            {{$todos_planos->nm_prodcomerc}}
          </div>
        @endforeach
```

Controller

```
$public function retorna_vendedor(Request $request){

 $dados = $request->all();

 $produto = new Produto();

 $produto_dados = $produto->select_vendedor();

 $cpf = $dados['nu_cpf'];

 $produto_dados = $produto->select_dinamico_vendedor($cpf);

 $produto_plano = $produto->select_planos($cpf);

 $todos_planos = $produto->select_todos_produtos_comerciais();

 return view('admin.vendedor.cadastrar_vendedor',
 compact('produto_dados','produto_plano','todos_planos'));
 }
```

I get this error `"Trying to get property 'id_produto' of non-object (View: /var/www/html/adminVendas/resources/views/admin/vendedor/cadastrar_vendedor.blade.php)"`

I think my code have something in syntax can someone help?

Comment: You're going to have an issue with both of your foreach loops, since you're overwriting the outer array with the inner value. Change the value on the right to a different variable name.

Comment: ´{{ $produto_plano->id_produto == $todos_planos->id_prodcomerc ? 'checked' : '' }}>´ Here?

Comment: No, here `@foreach($todos_planos as $key => $todos_planos)` and `@foreach($produto_plano as $produto_plano)`. The first loop will react fine. But because the variable name is the same on both sides, the left variable will be overwritten by the right variable, and you're suddenly iterating through the object properties instead of the array of objects on the second loop. A third loop just won't happen

Comment: Works very well! Very much thanks!